# How can i color my text in orange color?

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to find how to color my text in orange.

I tried this:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN);
```

But it will give me a red on green text.

Is it even possible to get the color orange? i tried different codes i found in the internet, but none of them gave me orange.

thanks for the help.

Comment: When you checked the internet, did you check the official documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_character_attributes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the following bit mask: `FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN`.

It will change the color of the **text** to orange. You may still want to experiment with `BACKGROUND_*` to adjust the background color to your needs.

Comment: It uses `FOREGROUND_GREEN` instead of `BACKGROUND_GREEN`, therefore giving orange color of the text. I believe this is what OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

` there is another way to change the color of text,,,,
infact you can also change the color of console.

use     `system("color xy")`     where x is the background color and y is the text color and dont forget to include dos and windows header file
here is the color table

FOR EXample

```
 #include <windows.h> /* code table   0 = Black       8 = Gray
 1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
 2 = Green       A = Light Green
 3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
 4 = Red         C = Light Red
 5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
 6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
 7 = White       F = Bright White */
 #include<dos.h>
 system("color 12");`
```